# Understanding architecture of Spark SQL

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, apache-spark

I'm not sure I understood correctly how Spark SQL works.

For example, it is not clear to me whether I need to already have hadoop and hive installed on a cluster. From the documentation, it looks like all you need to do is to download spark and install it on all the machines you want to use (and compile with the hive option if you wish to connect to a hive warehouse).

Also, if there is no need to connect to an already existing hive warehouse, it looks to me that the only other way to load data is via RDD, Parquet and JSON.

Is my overall understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark can run in stand alone mode( Single node no hadoop), on Mesos or on Hadoop(Yarn). 
You can run Spark SQL queries on any SchemaRDD or and a RDD consisting of case class objects(scala) or python dictionaries or Row objects.
Spark has built in methods to access Parquet and json. Datastax has an opensource spark-cassandra-connector that lets you read from cassandra. 
You could basically read any format and as long as you know how to parse it into an RDD of dictonaries/ case classes or Row objects you can run spark SQL on it.

Comment: does spark create a DFS if I don't have one already?

Comment: Spark does not create a DFS. You could read from HDFS/local disk.